# MySQL function not working

Tags: php, mysql

When I do

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE id= 2
```

The code works but when I write it like this:

```
$try= 2;
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE id= $try;
```

The code doesn't work anymore.  Can someone please explain?

Comment: Why do you think it would work the second time?

Comment: That's in no way valid code in any language. Please post real code or it's hard to tell what's going on here. Is this supposed to be all SQL? Or mixed SQL and PHP? Also define "doesn't work".

Comment: I am asking a question that i don't know ! WHy are you downvoting I need help

Comment: Replace `$` with `@` and try it again.

Comment: If you are writing it in php you have to put 
`"SELECT count(*) FROM tble_name WHERE id= '$try'" ` 
I think you are direct executing that query in phpmyAdmin. If yes, then this will not run becauase phpmyAdmin doesn't know $try. If no then pls write the error msg

Comment: Assuming this is php, your first step should be to echo out mysql_error() to see what's going on. Oh and the downvotes are because you didn't specify what language you are trying to do this in.

Comment: The second snippet says `tble_name` not `table_name`. I suppose this is a typo in the question, not in the actual code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to "include" your parameter properly into string

```
'SELECT count(*) FROM tble_name WHERE id='.$try;
```

Second, you have to pass it to [mysqli object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT count(*) FROM tble_name WHERE id='.$try);
```

Then you have to fetch result

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        /* your logic here */
    }
```

Obviously you have to create new `mysqli` object properly, as explained into link that I've provided you.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL use `@` symbol for the variables.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html for more information

Try this would work:

```
SET @try='test';
SELECT count(*) FROM tble_name WHERE id = @try;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$try= 2;
$sql=sprintf("SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE id=%d",$try);
```