# MySQL query doesn't work in website, works in MySQL program

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
mysql_query("
   SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, @concat := CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) 
   FROM tc 
   WHERE (@concat LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search_term']) ."%');");
```

search_term just refers to the value of a text input.

When I run the SELECT statement in sequel pro locally - my mysql program - it works perfectly, selecting the appropriate rows. When I run the query however locally through my PHP page, it returns no rows, even though it should. Help anyone?

Comment: Are you able to profile the mySql instance to see what command is reaching it?  (It's called "profiling" in MS SQL, not sure about mySql sorry).

Comment: Either not connected at all or not connected to the database you think you are.

Comment: What does it means it returns "no row" ? Have you execute the statement or only declared it? Have yo fetched any row? Please, take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367798/mysql-function-not-working/12367856#12367856)

Comment: last line of query `);");` makes me confuse

Comment: Have you checked whether the query executed or it failed? Are you sure you are 1) connected at all 2) connected to the right database? Are you sure your query is even valid?

Comment: @diEcho: the first parenthesis is to close the WHERE clause parentheses, the semi-colon ends the SELECT clause, the second parenthesis closes the mysql_query and the final semi-colon ends the query. I don't know why that confuses you.

Comment: @N.B.: yes, it is connected fine and it is valid, as it works when I run it directly in mysql locally.

Comment: So, judging by the answer - the query was not valid. Always doubt yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` does not work on calculated columns, therefore your query, per se, **will not work**.

It probably works because you locally have a `@concat` variable declared. It will also **appear** to work if you run the query twice in specific conditions, because your query might actually assign a `@concat` variable.

What you want is

```
SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position,
    CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname)  AS concat
FROM tc HAVING concat LIKE '%<YOUR SEARCH TERM>%';
```

As test:

```
-- Declare a minimum table to match the query
CREATE TABLE tc (id integer, firstname varchar(20), surname varchar(20), position integer);

INSERT INTO tc (firstname, surname) VALUES ('alfa', 'bravo');

-- Your query...

SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position,
    @concat := CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) FROM tc WHERE (@concat LIKE '%alfa%');

-- ...returns nothing

Empty set (0.00 sec)

-- The proper query works.

SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname)  AS concat FROM tc HAVING concat LIKE '%alfa%';
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
| tc_id | firstname | surname | position | concat     |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
|  NULL | alfa      | bravo   |     NULL | alfa bravo |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- But if I declare a @concat variable    

SELECT @concat := 'alfa';
+-------------------+
| @concat := 'alfa' |
+-------------------+
| alfa              |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- Then your query SEEMS to work.

mysql> SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, @concat := CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname)  FROM tc  WHERE (@concat LIKE '%alfa%');
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| tc_id | firstname | surname | position | @concat := CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  NULL | alfa      | bravo   |     NULL | alfa bravo                               |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- "SEEMS" because the select query isn't actually working:

UPDATE tc SET firstname = 'delta';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.28 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

-- Having renamed the only row to "delta", a search for "alpha" should fail,
-- but since @concat still holds 'alpha', then the query matches ALL rows:

mysql> SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, @concat := CONCAT(firstname,'    ',surname)  FROM tc  WHERE (@concat LIKE '%alfa%');
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| tc_id | firstname | surname | position | @concat := CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  NULL | delta     | bravo   |     NULL | delta bravo                              |
+-------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: this was indeed the issue. Thank you, lserni.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
mysql_query("
   SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) as concatt 
   FROM tc 
   WHERE (CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search_term']) ."%');");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your Sequel Pro translate the query statement to become MySql query, and MySql not understand what mean about "where @concat LIKE...".

Try change your where clause on PHP code become "where CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) LIKE '%..."

bellow the complete code:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id as tc_id, firstname, surname, position, CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) FROM tc WHERE (CONCAT(firstname,' ',surname) LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['search_term']) ."%');");
```